# Oracle APEX - Storing color picker value

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to save the color picker value to a column.

The user can pick color for dashboard like this:
[image]

I created a dynamic action for Save button and its action is Submit Page. I also created Process after submit to update the table. I set PL/SQL code like this:

```
UPDATE USR 
SET SETTING_PREF = '{"attention": &P7_ATTENTION., "property": &P7_PROPERTY., "not_reported": &P7_NOT_REPORTED., "off_property": &P7_OFF_PROPERTY., "carts_in_use": &P7_CARTS_IN_USE., "carts_idle": &P7_CARTS_IDLE., "show_item_num": &P7_SHOW_ITEM_NUM., "language": &P7_LANGUAGE.}'
WHERE EMAIL = :APP_USER;
```

But somehow, the values do not seem to be saved to the SETTING_PREF column.
There is no error message after I click the save button, so I'm assuming that I am not retrieving the correct values from color picker section.
Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&ITEM.` notation cannot be used within pl/sql. Within pl/sql use the bind variable notation (`:ITEM`). Change the statement to (up to you to complete the json):

```
UPDATE USR 
SET SETTING_PREF = apex_string.format('{"attention": %0,"property": %1, "not_reported": %2}', :P7_ATTENTION, :P7_PROPERTY, :P7_NOT_REPORTED)
WHERE EMAIL = :APP_USER;
```

The api `apex_string.format` isn't needed but it avoids having to concat that long string with all the bind variables.

Also... why the dynamic action ? Just define a page process with the when-button-pressed condition. Dynamic action is overkill.

Comment: I didn't know why &ITEM. doesn't work there. It's working now, thank you very much for your answer! For dynamic action, I want to submit the page when it's clicked. So for Action, I set Submit Page

Comment: &ITEM. doesn't work because it is only valid for html subsitution: when something is rendered on the page as html, as part of a link, etc. In pl/sql blocks, it's exclusively bind variable syntax.